# Meteor not automatically loading stylesheets placed in /public

Tags: meteor, static-files

**public/img/logo.png**

**client/views/common/common.html**

```
<div id="logo-container" class="brand-logo">logo</div>
```

**public/styles/main.css**

```
.brand-logo {   background-image: url("/img/logo.png"); }
```

Going to Chrome DevTools' resources tab, neither the image, nor the stylesheet is loaded.

In fact in elements tab (right area) the class is not applied to the element. The template is rendered properly instead (in fact "logo" **text** is printed)

Comment: I presume the app hasn't restarted yet if you don't have the 'class' attribute added to your div

Comment: Move the css file from the `public` folder to the `client` folder. "Public" css files are not automatically compiled or linked in your HTML.

Comment: @BrianShamblen is correct, either that or you'd be hardcoding link tags to link the CSS, which defeats the purpose of using Meteor's compiling / templating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a "stylesheets" folder inside the "client" directory and place the main.css file inside there.

```
client/stylesheets/main.css
```

Meteor will automatically load any .css files if you place them in this directory, so you don't need to reference it.

Currently, you have main.css file in public/styles/main.css

Comment: thank you @meteorBuzz. 
However isn't **public** supposed to be **the** folder to serve static content?

Comment: @dragonmnl Nope, it's the folder supposed to serve _deferred_ static content, as in images, styles or scripts you don't want to be loaded inside your app automatically, etc.

Comment: public folder is used to store things like images and favicons.

Comment: ok will check asap your answer and accept it afterwards.
But why the way I made it doesn't actually load the css? that was my original question

Comment: it works, if you could enlight me on the last question (see comment above) would be wonderful